# Any ideas, how to encode QR data into png image?

Tags: qt, base64, png, embed, qr-code

All I need is simple *(Q)string* to put it as embedded image like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...">
```

I use: `#include <qrencode.h>`  (linux -> apt-get install libqrencode-dev)

This is my code:

```
QRcode *qr=QRcode_encodeString(QString("my test string").toStdString().c_str(), 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8,1);
QByteArray *ba = new QByteArray();
for (unsigned int y=0; y<qr->width;y++)
{
    int yy=y*qr->width;
    for (unsigned int x=0; x<qr->width;x++)
    {
      int xx=yy+x;
      const unsigned char b=qr->data[xx];

      ///WHAT TO DO NOW??? IS IT CORRECT?
      ba->push_back(b);
      qDebug()<<"Char "<<b;   
      if(b &0x01)
      {
        qDebug()<<"Point +++";  
      }
    }
}

qDebug()<<ba->toBase64();
```

Any ideas, how to encode `qr->data`  into a *png* image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! :)
First version, without scaling

```
    #include<QString>
    #include<QDebug>
    #include<QByteArray>
    #include<QBuffer>
    #include<QImage>
    #include<QImageWriter>
    #include<QPixmap>
    #include<QPainter>
    #include<QColor>
    #include<QPointF>
    #include<QRectF>



    //ustawiam kolory
    QColor bialy = Qt::white;
    QColor czarny = Qt::black;

//PNG    
        QByteArray ImageAsByteArray;
        QBuffer ImageBuffer(&ImageAsByteArray);
        ImageBuffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);




    QRcode *qr=QRcode_encodeString(QString("afya.pl").toStdString().c_str(), 1, QR_ECLEVEL_L, QR_MODE_8,1);

    QPixmap p(qr->width,qr->width);
    QPainter pa;
    pa.begin(&p);
    pa.setRenderHints(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing |QPainter::TextAntialiasing| QPainter::Antialiasing);
    pa.setPen(bialy);
    pa.setBrush(bialy);
    //czyścimy tło
    QPointF a=QPointF(0.0,0.0);
    QPointF b=QPointF(p.width(),p.height());
    pa.drawRect(QRectF(a,b));


    pa.setPen(czarny);

    for (unsigned int y=0; y<qr->width;y++)
    {
        int yy=y*qr->width;
        for (unsigned int x=0; x<qr->width;x++)
        {
        int xx=yy+x;
        const unsigned char b=qr->data[xx];

        if(b &0x01){
    a=QPointF(y,x);
    pa.drawPoint(a);
        }
        }


    }
    p.save(&ImageBuffer,"PNG");


    qDebug()<<ImageAsByteArray.toBase64();
    }
```

Comment: Setting individual pixels is even easier if you use `QImage` instead fof `QPixmap`, i.e. with `QImage::setPixel()` instead of using `QPainter::drawPoint()`. Depending on the format ot `qr->data` it might even be possible to convert that directly into a `QImage`